# Menu height not reset when resising screen

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm doing responsive design where the menu is replaced with a menu button when width <= 768px;

Currently I'm using jQuery to change the height of the menu when I click the menu button.
The jQuery adds `style="height: 152px;"` to the `nav` element and the CSS3 `transition: height 0.35s ease 0s;` makes sure it slides down greacefully.

This works fine until I resize the window while the menu is visible. When the `width > 768px`, the menu items are floated next to each other (so they are on one line instead of below each other).

The problem is that the menu height is still 152px high and causes empty space below the menu.

I've tried to see if there is a listener that can detect if the menu button becomes hidden (`display: none;`) so that I can remove the `style`, but I've not found anything yet.

Is there a simple solution to my problem? Any help appreciated.

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCAht/2/)

```
// CSS
.nav-collapse {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.35s ease 0s;
}

@media (max-width: 768px){
  .collapse { height:0; }
}

// JS
  $('.btn-navbar').click(function(){
    var nav = $('.nav-collapse');

    if($(nav).hasClass('collapse')){
      $(nav).height($(nav).find('ul').height());
      $(nav).removeClass('collapse');
    } else {
      $(nav).attr('style','');
      $(nav).addClass('collapse');
    }
  });

// HTML
<nav class="nav-collapse collapse">
  <ul>
    <li> menu items </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You should try to replicate your problem in a fiddle. Sometimes it's hard for us to visualize your problem based on your description alone.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the behavior you are looking for is the menu to uncollapse itself when the viewport gets bigger, and the height to be automatically calculated by the browser. You simply have to listen to the window resize event, and determine what to do if the screen size gets bigger than the threshold you have set (I see that your desired threshold is 600px in your fiddle):

```
$w.resize(function () {
    // Uncollapse navigation when viewport gets bigger
    if ($w.width() > 600) {
        $nav.css({
            height: "auto"    // Adjusts nav height to auto
        });
    }
});
```

Since we are also referencing to the $nav variable here, I suggest you move the declaration higher up, like in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/wCAht/5/):

```
var $nav = $('.nav-collapse'), // I recommend using $var for objects, so you don't get confused with general variables
    $w = $(window),            // The $(window) object
    threshold = 600;           // You can change this to a pixel value that you want

// Listen to click event
$('.btn-navbar').click(function () {

    // NOTE: I have taken the liberty to change your $(nav) to $nav for consistency
    if ($nav.hasClass('collapse')) {
        $nav.height($nav.find('ul').height()); // If removed, transition does not work.
        $nav.removeClass('collapse');
    } else {
        $nav.attr('style', ''); // If removed, transition does not work.
        $nav.addClass('collapse');
    }
});

// Listen to resize event
$w.resize(function () {
    // Uncollapse navigation when viewport gets bigger
    if ($w.width() > threshold) {
        $nav.css({
            height: "auto"    // Adjusts nav height to auto
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the height as an inline style – add a class instead with jQuery that defines the target height, and make that class apply only within the `max-width: 768px` media query – then once that media query is not applicable any more, the height will also not be set to that fixed value any more.

Comment: I've tried that, but then `transition: height` is not working :(